# Mongodb architecture required

Tags: mongodb

I am creating a project that requires data storage and I am considering useing MongoDB but am having trouble finding the logical / optimal way of organising the data

My simplified data needs to store Place information like so:

```
{place_city : "London",
place_owner: "Tim",
place_name: "Big Ben"}

{place_city : "Paris",
place_owner: "Tim",
place_name: "Eifel Tower"}

{place_city : "Paris", 
place_owner: "Ben",
place_name: "The Louvre"}
```

And here are the main operations I need

```
Retrieve all my places
Retrieve all my friends places
Retrieve all my friends cities
```

If I use mongoDB a collection document max size is 16meg right? If that is correct then I can't store all the information in a PLACES similar to my example above right?

I would probably need to create a "OWNER" collection? like so:

```
{
  owner: "Tim", 
  cities: [ {
             name: "London",
             places:[ {name:"Big Ben"}]
            },
            {
             name: "Paris",
             places:[ {name:"Eifel Tower"}, {name: "The Louvre"}]
            }
           ]
}
```

but the problem now is that Retrieving my friends places becomes cumbersome and my friends cities even more so....

any advice from a cunning DB architect woudl be much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but the document size limit applies to individual documents. In your example, `{place_city : "London", place_owner: "Tim", place_name: "Big Ben"}` is one document, but you can have any number of documents inside a collection.

Comment: It is true that the data will fit in a document, but with MongoDB anytime you are asking yourself whether your document will be large enough to store all the data you will EVENTUALLY have, you probably have a design problem on your hands. If a document's growth is unbound, it should probably be enumerated within a collection instead (within reason).

Comment: How do you know who your friends are? Do you know your friend's name already or do you find that out from the database also?

Comment: Friends are stored in another DB, for arguments sake, let's say you get your friends by querying the Facebook API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I love MongoDB, but this data is not a good candidate for MongoDB. MongoDB does not support relationships, and that is basically all you are tracking here. Use a relational database to store the relationships.

Think of it like this: under the skin of the DBMS, MongoDB or SQL, an index is an index, a table is a table (basically). You get more performance from MongoDB not because it does the same things faster, but because you are able to use it to get your DB server to do less. (E.g. pull an entire document containing nested arrays and subdocs instead of joining a bunch of tables together). There are some fundamental differences in the way MongoDB handles updates, but for querying simple data sets most systems are going to be relatively similar. One big difference between the two rooted in the way MongoDB works is that it cannot use data in a collection as parameters for a another query, which is basically the whole point of a relational database. Since 2 of your use cases require "joins" (to "all my friends"), you need two queries.

So what you're doing with two queries is the same thing as a join, except relational databases are optimized to do this extremely efficiently; I promise you it will be slower to do this join manually, plus you're sending all data (friends' IDs) over the wire and making an extra DB connection. Now, if you could store all your friends' cities and places in a single document, MongoDB will probably be (slightly) faster than joining, but now you've got a new problem, because you now have to manage all this, anytime anyone adds a city or place all their friends have to be modified--this is unrealistic.

But there is even more to the story than that, because SQL DBMS are extremely mature applications with lots of features to improve query performance. They let you do things like create "materialize views" that store all your friends cities and places in memory and update themselves automatically any time one of their source tables is updated so you don't have to do anything special, you'd just query and you'd get your data without actually executing any joins. (A materialized table is not the right fit here, but just as an example, it is possible if you needed it.)

ALSO, when you are using MongoDB, a guideline I've found helpful is this, anytime you are asking yourself whether your document will be large enough to store all the data you will EVENTUALLY have, you probably have a design problem on your hands. If a document's growth is unbound, it should probably be enumerated within a collection instead. Or put another way, your collections should grow as your application is used, not your document's size (much).

If breaking apart your schema like this means that for primary operations you are doing a lot of manual joins, it is worth considering the question of whether or not you should be using a relational database instead.

Comment: When it's all about relations, a graph-database like Neo4j might be even better for this.

Comment: @Philipp, yeah for sure.

Comment: -1 @Paul this data is no more relational that many very successful MongoDB production implementations (although it's unclear how the OP is tracking friends). The key reason to use relational DB is to prevent data duplication, which is not a stated goal in the question. So your advice is in fact quite misleading here.

Comment: That is hardly the key reason. Referential integrity is far more important than data duplication. The OP's example data is a classic example of where not to use MongoDB.

Comment: @Paul is the concept of referential integrity not closely linked to the prevention of data duplication? In either case, neither RI nor prevention of duplication are requirements for the OP.

Comment: No, not at all. That's just an example anyway. Duplicate away, memory savings is no longer a very important concern in DB design. The problem for MongoDB in a system like this is that you are picking a "winner" or primary direction for the data to be accessed. The OP lists three MAIN operations (there may be others), but is already running into trouble with a read operation that would be trivial in a SQL RDBMS. In my experience these kinds of problems only will get worse as you go. NoSQL DBs are specialized tools, and baring some missing details, I don't see any benefit to using MongoDB here.

Comment: @Paul read operations are not hard in MongoDB as shown in Derick's answer. They can actually perform better than a SQL solution requiring JOINs.

Comment: But you are doing joins! Two of the three "main operations" require two round-trips to the server. This gets out of hand very quickly. If I have a thousand friends and each of them has 1-5 cities on average, assuming some duplicates (the OP isn't specific on these details, I'm just giving an example) I'm sending perhaps orders of magnitude more data over the wire than I'm actually interested in retrieving. I'll grant you it is **possible** that the specific case here **could** be solved efficiently with MongoDB, but even in that case I don't see any benefits to this over a relational DBMS.

Comment: Thank you both for this comment exchange, this is very helpful. I think both arguments are very valid. @Paul, are you implicitly saying that a large SQL table will handle it's self better / faster than a large collection?

Comment: ^ updated the answer instead

Answer (score 1):

The size limit of 16MB is per document, not per collection.

```
{place_city : "London", place_owner: "Tim", place_name: "Big Ben"}
```

is a very little document, so don't worry. The design of your collections depends heavily on how you query your data.

Answer (score 1):

The data size limitation is per **document** and not per **collection**. Collections can easily become several GB (or even TB) large.

I would suggest you keep your data as simple as you have, like:

```
{place_city : "London",
place_owner: "Tim",
place_name: "Big Ben"}

{place_city : "Paris",
place_owner: "Tim",
place_name: "Eifel Tower"}

{place_city : "Paris", 
place_owner: "Ben",
place_name: "The Louvre"}
```

I am thinking that friends are stored like this:

```
{
     username: "Ben",
     friends: [ "Tim", "Bob" ]
}
```

Then your three queries can be done as:

1. All your places: `db.places.find( { place_owner: "Ben" } );`
2. All your friends' places with two queries (pseudo code):

   ```
   friends = db.friends.find( { username: "Ben" } );
   // friends = [ "Tim", "Bob" ], you do need to do some code to make this change
   db.places.find( { place_owner: { $in: [ "Tim", "Bob" ] } } );
   ```
3. All your friends' cities with two queries (pseudo code):

   ```
   friends = db.friends.find( { username: "Ben" } );
   db.so.distinct( 'name', { place_owner: { $in: [ "Tim", "Bob" ] } } );
   ```

Even with millions of documents, this should work fine, providing you have an index on the fields that you query for: `{ place_owner: 1 }` and `{ username: 1 }`.

Comment: thank you Derik, I think this is what I will do, it's pretty straight forward. I would have to ask though, if the collections holds millions of documents, any idea how will this effect the overall performance?

Comment: Updated my answer to talk about the indexes.